# How to lock a specific Object in Python to provide Race-Conditions?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, semaphore, race-condition

I'm trying to implement an API for a Roboter using Python. The Roboter has an amount ot motor objects, which are implemented in the class Motor. There's a funkction called moveMotor which runes in a thread.

```
""" Motor Class """
class Motor:

    def __init__(self, motor_id):
        """
        @param motor_id: Motor Identity
        @type motor_id: int
        """
        self.__motor_id = motor_id
        self.__motorState = "r"

        def moveMotor(self):
            thread = MotorThread(self)
            thread.start()

        def run(self):      
        print("Motor starts...")
        i = 0
        while(i < 3):
            print("Wrrrmmmmmmmmmm")
            time.sleep(1)
            i+=1
```

My Problem is, that I cannot find a possibility to implement a lock or a semaphore, which denies access only, when one specific Motor is in use.
So when Motor 1 moves the Motor, Motor 2 can move the Motor, too. But if there is another Thread calling Motor 1 to move, it has to wait.

I tried it with `lock = threading.Lock()` and `lock = threading.Semaphore()` in the Motor Class and in the MotorThread Class, and acquired and released, yeah since now really everywhere, to test. But I couldn't find a solution.

Thank you, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: A instance lock on the motor class will work just fine.